# Calculating a column from Another column using a condition in R

Tags: r, loops, conditional-statements

I have a data frame like;

```
 
method               SOC
walkley black        0.5
walkley black        1.2
combustion           0.8
combustion           0.7
```

I want to make a new column called new_SOC.
I want to multiply SOC by 10 and put it in new_SOC.
I want to do this only for walkley black method and others to be NA.

I made the following codes but I was not successful:
I appreciate your help.

```
## make an empty column called new_SOC
df$new_SOC <- c("")
## Make a loop to calculate the new column with condition.
for (i in 1:length(df)){
   if (df$method == " walkley black")  {
      df$new_SOC = df$SOC*10
      }
   else{df$new_SOC == "NA"}
   }
```

Comment: Please, use `dtput()` or `reprex::reprex()` to provide sample data.

Answer (score 1):

Using dplyr, you can:

```
library(dplyr)
df <- df %>% 
  mutate(new_SOC = ifelse(method == " walkley black", 10*SOC, NA))
```

But, if walkley black is written in different ways:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
  df <- df %>% 
  mutate(new_SOC = ifelse(str_detect(method,"walkley black"), 10*SOC, NA))
```

Comment: Thanks, Jose, Your help is wonderful and appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ifelse` :

```
df$new_SOC  <- ifelse(df$method == "walkley black", df$SOC*10, NA)
```

Comment: Thanks, Ronak for your help.

Answer (score 0):

We can also use `case_when`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 <- df %>%
         mutate(new_SOC = case_when(method == "walkley black" ~ SOC * 10))
```

---

Or using `base R`

```
i1 <- df$method == 'walkley black"
df$new_SOC[i1] <- df$SOC[i1] * 10
```