# Calculate a new column from values and conditions in the other columns in R

Tags: r

I have a csv table like this loaded in R.

| method | SOC | SOC2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| WB | 1.5 |  |
| Com | 2.5 |  |
| LOI | 3.1 |  |

I want to calculate column "SOC2" with conditions from method column like as follows:
If the method in the method column is WB, multiply SOC by 10 and put it in SOC2 column.
If the method in the method column is Com, multiply SOC by 20 and put it in SOC2 column.
if the method in the method column is LOI, multiply SOC by 30 and out ut ub SOC2 Column.

How can I do that in R please?

Comment: Please use the `R`s `dput`-function for providing us sample-data. If your data is loaded in a variable called `df`, please expand your question with the output of `dput(df)`.

Comment: You can utilise the answers from your previous question to do this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65747420/calculating-a-column-from-another-column-using-a-condition-in-r Additionally, it would be good to see your attempt at solving this.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```r
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(method = c("WB", "Com", "LOI"), SOC = c(1.5, 2.5, 3.1))

df %>% mutate(SOC2 = case_when(
  method == "WB" ~ SOC * 10, 
  method == "Com" ~ SOC * 20, 
  method == "LOI" ~ SOC * 30
))

  method SOC SOC2
1     WB 1.5   15
2    Com 2.5   50
3    LOI 3.1   93
```

Comment: This is a very nice method. Thanks, Leonardo.

Comment: You're welcome! If my answer was helpful, if you want accept it

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
wbIndices <- df$method == "WB"
ComIndices <- df$method == "Com"
LOIIndices <- df$method == "LOI"

df$SOC2 <- df$SOC[wbIndices]*10
df$SOC2 <- df$SOC[ComIndices]*20
df$SOC2 <- df$SOC[LOIIndices]*30
```

Comment: This method is great. Thanks, Jonas.